# Simple solution for calling a function only on one thread, queuing waiting calls?

Tags: multithreading, posix, semaphore, mutex

Let’s assume there is a function `EventHandler` that is called on multiple threads at different points in time.

`EventHandler` has to call `SomeOtherFunction`, *but* these calls shall only happen on one thread at a time.

That means: If a call to `SomeOtherFunction` is currently active on thread A, and `EventHandler` gets called again (on some other thread B), then `SomeOtherFunction` must not be called on thread B, but `SomeOtherFunction` shall be called when it returns on thread A.

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
function EventHandler()
{
  numberPendingCallsSemaphore.Release();    // increase
  if (mayCallSemaphore.Acquire())           // (i)
  {
    while (numberPendingCallsSemaphore.Acquire())  // decrease
    {
      SomeOtherFunction();
    }
    // (ii)
    mayCallSemaphore.Release();
  }
}
```

Of course, this code does *not* work because of a race: One thread is at position (ii) with `mayCallSemaphore` still being taken, and another at position (i) not being able to take `mayCallSemaphore`.

I wrote working code using a lock, but the code is quite long and ugly. On the other, this problem looks quite simple at first sight, thus:

Is there a simple, potentially straightforward solution for this I was not able to find or currently don’t see?

Comment: It's called "blocking on synchronous functions."  When you call a function, it blocks the flow of execution until it is completed, thereby allowing the next function to execute.  It's not a software pattern; it's merely the inevitable consequence of calling functions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don’t understand how this is related to my question. Of course a (synchronous) call to a function will block. Please let me know if I should reword my question.

Comment: The problem with your question is that it makes the wrong assumptions about software patterns.  Software patterns are not a "cookbook."  For the most part, they address inadequacies in the programming language you are using; by definition, they have very limited scope.

Comment: Use a Mutex and a Condition Variable to implement a Counting Semaphore. There are Posix compliant versions in all Unix variants and Windows NT (I did this a long time ago).

Comment: @nocomprende A semaphore doesn’t remove the race between one thread releasing it (incrementing its count), after the thread being busy doing the calls checked its count (tries to acquire it) and before leaving the loop. Lock required -> code gets long and ugly, and when there already is a lock, it’s trivial to replace the semaphore with an integer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, removed the word “pattern” and the tag.

Comment: Mutex provides exclusive access to the Condition Variable, which controls the sleep / wakeup behavior. Your code is almost identical to what it should be, just grok the Condition Variable semantics and you have it. I guess the question is whether you actually *need* a counting semaphore - you might not be placing a limit - but that is my take on your question. I used it, it works in industrial strength situation. And can be implemented portably on all OS. If I had my code from my old job, I would give it as an Answer. Sorry.

Comment: @nocomprende Maybe I just don’t see it, but I think that still leaves room for a race. Do you want to take my code, make the modification, and post it as answer? I’ll be happy to accept and upvote :)

Comment: [GitHub doco link](https://github.com/angrave/SystemProgramming/wiki/Synchronization,-Part-5:-Condition-Variables)

Comment: @nocomprende Please see my last edit. Hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: What environment are you working in?  What you describe sounds very much like the [Single Threaded Apartment Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112(v=vs.85).aspx) used in Microsoft's COM and ActiveX and (in some situations) .NET frameworks.

Comment: Related: [Producer–consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)

Comment: I feel like finding a library that provides an implementation of a Concurrent Queue (thread-safe queue) could solve this problem? You could have the event handlers just add the items to the queue, and a worker thread that dequeues and executes them.

Comment: @Jules To be honest, I'd prefer not to reveal what initially led to my question, because I fear that would distract too much from the question. I found the question interesting on its own. (It has nothing to do with COM and/or STA.)

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I agree, with a concurrent queue this problem can be solved with some trivial code. However that would mean that one thread does nothing but waits, and eventually dequeues and executes. And it does not matter if it's a dedicated thread or a thread from a worker thread pool, the thread is burnt. Imho not that elegant.

Comment: Threads are going cheap these days. I remember back when I was implementing a method to share modems across a Novell network of DOS PCs, I had to handle the problem of *re-entrancy* for Interrupt Service Routines that called in to the DOS core code (never designed to be re-entrant). Somehow I managed this, with the help of a book about writing Interrupt routines from the local bookstore (this was 1992). Had to buy a second book because there was an error in the first that had me stumped - missing line of code. Debugging DOS TSRs is a lonely job. Read up on re-entrancy / thread-safety?

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: There's a joke in here somewhere about 'starvation' or lost notifications or something...

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed solution has two control objects. `mayCallSemaphore` looks like a **Mutex** based on how you are using it, and `numberPendingCallsSemaphore` appears to serve as a **Condition Variable**. You have it almost correct, but as you surmised, having two control structures that operate independently leads to race conditions, deadlock or both depending on the topology and situation. Lost wakeups and other things are also possible.

If you take a close look at this [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/angrave/SystemProgramming/wiki/Synchronization,-Part-5:-Condition-Variables) about how to construct a Counting Semaphore using **both a Mutex and a Condition Variable**, you will see that the CV actually uses (cooperates with) the Mutex internally, so there can be no races or deadlocks. I will copy and paste the example solution right here for convenience:

```
typedef struct sem_t {
  int count; 
  pthread_mutex_t m;
  pthread_condition_t cv;
} sem_t;

int sem_init(sem_t *s, int pshared, int value) {
  if (pshared) { errno = ENOSYS /* 'Not implemented'*/; return -1;}

  s->count = value;
  pthread_mutex_init(&s->m, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&s->cv, NULL);
  return 0;
}

sem_post(sem_t *s) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&s->m);
  s->count++;
  pthread_cond_signal(&s->cv); /* See note */
  /* A woken thread must acquire the lock, so it will also have to wait until we call unlock*/

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&s->m);
}

sem_wait(sem_t *s) {
  pthread_mutex_lock(&s->m);
  while (s->count == 0) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&s->cv, &s->m); /*unlock mutex, wait, relock mutex*/
  }
  s->count--;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&s->m);
}
```

Simply protect your call to `SomeOtherFunction()` by calling `sem_wait()` before and then calling `sem_post()` after. The internals of the methods will take care of all of the details, causing concurrent accesses to block, allowing only one execution of your code's critical section at a time. This is all based on the Posix primitives which are part of the OS and cannot go wrong. In your case, the count should be restricted to one, so you can either simplify this code, or initialize the semaphore with 1 and make use of the same code for another situation later.

I have used this same approach - taken from the POSIX manual pages (about 20 years ago) - to create a multi-threaded, multi-process database transaction server before the Apache web server was multi-threaded. I had one main thread that accepts incoming TCP connections, and creates up to 'N' work threads at a time (transient, not a pool). It worked for a long time in a very large site with many users. Unix gives you the tools to construct proper solutions, you just need to put them together.

Comment: Note: you *must* have a While loop around the call to pthread_cond_wait() even if you restrict the maximum count to 1. There are various possibilities for false wakeups, etc that are handled by this loop.